# Crontab does not work

Tags: cron

I have 2 crontab commands.

The cron below works fine:

```
00 19 * * * cp -a /home/kmportal/VirtualBox\ VMs/cyn.in-disk1.vmdk /media/windowsshare
```

The cron below does not work after I add the time behind:

```
05 09 * * * cp -a /home/kmportal/VirtualBox\ VMs/cyn.in-disk1.vmdk /media/windowsshare/'date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S'cyn.in-disk1.vmdk
```

Please guide me to understand the command and how to solve.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you used the wrong tick, you used `'` instead of `. Try

```
05 09 * * * cp -a /home/kmportal/VirtualBox\ VMs/cyn.in-disk1.vmdk /media/windowsshare/`date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S`cyn.in-disk1.vmdk
```

Comment: Percent signs have special significance in cron, you need to backslash escape them - see [How can I execute `date` inside of a cron tab job?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29578/how-can-i-execute-date-inside-of-a-cron-tab-job)

Comment: Thanks noleti but it still the same

Comment: steeldriver dude. Yes you are right. Its because of the backslash. Thank man. -date +\%Y\%m\%d\%H\%M\%S-->works